# SSRS subreport with parameter rendering only one record of group

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, visual-studio-2008

I  want to build a report that returns records for a group of employees and by specific dates and supervisor, and renders the report by employee (as in a batch).  I am doing this with a main report and 3 subreports.  My subreports work individually and I just got one subreport to render from main but only the 1st record in the group displays.

Dataset on main has 3 parameters, USERID, BegDate, EndDate.  Dataset on subreport take EMPID, BegDate, EndDate.  I inserted subreport on main and subreport parameters as follows:

```
    Name      Value

    CurEmp     =First(Fields!EMPID.Value, "DataSet1")
    BegDate    [@BegDate]
    EndDate    [@EndDate]
```

Where `CurEmp` is used in the where clause of DataSet1/sql query i.e. `WHERE EMPID = @CurEmp`

Main report parameters in DataSet1 are:

```
Name     Value
@USERID     [@USERID]
@BegDate    [@BegDate]
@EndDate    [@EndDate]
```

Now I realize that the `=First` in the Expression in `Value` of parameter is supposed to render only the first record but nothing I change it to will render at all.  I have done [tutorials](http://ssrstutorials.blogspot.com/2012/10/lesson-17-ssrs-subreports.html) and googled for 2 days. I can get the simple subreports to work but nothing seems to apply to what I am trying to do.  Can someone direct me to an example that applies to my situation?

BTW I have set my VS2008 environment to a Business Inteligence Project.

**UPDATE:**  I have added my sql queries below to help explain per suggestion by @Sam.  I actually was starting to look at the fact that maybe I am writing the queries wrong. I am confused about what the main report query should be compared to subquery....I hope this helps to clarify my meaning.

**Main report dataset =**

```
SELECT
v.EMPID,
UPPER(p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName)  as EmpFullName, 
v.dtmDate,  
v.TCode,  
v.Hours, 
v.ProjectNo,  
from vwPersonSummary v
join tblPerson t on v.EMPID = p.EMPID
WHERE  v.USERID = @USERID  --Supervisor’s EMPID
AND 
v.dtmDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @EndDate  
ORDER BY v.EMPID, v.dtmDate
```

**Subreport dataset=**

```
SELECT
v.EMPID,
UPPER(p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName)  as EmpFullName, 
v.dtmDate, 
v.Tcode,  
v.Hours, 
v.ProjectNo  
from vwPersonSummary v
join tblPerson t on v. EMPID = t. EMPID
WHERE
v.EMPID =  @CurEmp 
AND v.dtmDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @EndDate 
ORDER BY v.dtmDate
```

Comment: If we have some sample data it would make it bit clearer. **Where CurEmp is used in the where clause of DataSet1/sql query i.e. WHERE EMPID = @CurEmp** is confusing as well.

Comment: @Sam I updated my question with the queries

Comment: So what you are saying is that no records are being populated to the second report? Without any filters just bind the EmpId field from DataSet1 to a grid in the second report and check if you can get data there. I just want to check data gets populated to DataSet1.

Comment: ok, I placed a table inside a rectangle on main report and placed 2 fields, EMPID and EmpFullName in the table.  The subreport is inside the same rectangle.  In Preview all the employees in the supervisor's group are listed over several pages.  Is that what you meant?  Without the table, I get error message on subreport: "[rsWarningExecutingSubreport] Warnings occurred while executing the subreport ‘Subreport2’.
  [rsNone] The value provided for the report parameter 'CurEmp' is not valid for its type."

Comment: Ok so that means we get data for dataSet1 in sub report. Just to clarify when you run this you don't get any record in sub report or you get records of only one employee?

Comment: No records are returned in the subreport. Subreport resides inside 2nd column of my row group. (EmpID textbox is in 1st column and it does return the correct group of EMPID's). In Preview the subreport shows an empty table (I can see the table outline with column headings but that's it.) I have reduced the number of elements on the main report page to a table1 (tablix), and a subreport. The Row Groups hierarchy looks like this: [ EMPID > [(Group1) > (Static)

Comment: BTW looking at these queries for main report and sub report, what is the difference that you expect in them? It seems both are going to be same ultimately.

Comment: The difference is the main query returns only the supervisors' (USERID) employee's (EMPID) (i.e. not all employees) and the subquery's return only that employees records, namely hours by project and overall hours in the pay period. Ultimately I expect to return in the 3 subreports the sum of  "Hours" by supervisor and by employee: [by project] and [overall total hours]. I will try your suggestion and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

So your fix/answer is going to be something like below.

When defining the the parameter from the main report it should be something like this.

```sql
=Join(LookupSet(1,1,Fields!EMPID.Value,"DataSet1"),",")
```

Once that is defined make sure that the sub report parameter Data Type is set as **Text** and **Allow multiple values** have been checked.

After that for the data set of the sub report don't set a where condition. Instead in Data Set properties go to **Filters**.

In **Expression** set something like

```sql
=CStr(Fields!EMPID.Value)
```

and set **Operator** as **In** and set the **Value** as something like below.

```sql
=Split(Parameters!EmpId.Value(0),",")
```

Well basically that's it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the steps though I wasn't exactly sure where to place the =Join/LookupSet( etc etc) function.  I placed it in the Parameter Value expression field for CurEmp in the subreport properties from the main report page. Question: if I eliminate the WHERE clause in subreport dataset, how does the @CurEmp parameter get used ? Also apparently the LookupSet function doesn't work with SSRS 2008 (I don't have 2008 R2). I get a red squiggly line "unrecognized identifier" in the expression box. In Preview I get error: "Subreport contains an error: [BC30451} Name 'LookupSet' is not declared".

Comment: The place where you places the parameter is correct. The where clause will be handled by the filter part where you put in your filter condition. As for the SSRS version bump. Trying to do it in 2008 would involve going around with multiple datasets.

Comment: I didn't mark Sam's answer as correct because it doesn't work in my version of SSRS 2008 but I do understand in theory. Thank you Sam - this will certainly help others. I ended up starting over using row groups in (3) nested lists with a tablix in one list and freeform textboxes in the other 2 lists and one dataset with 3 parameters.  I realized (with your prodding) that I didn't need the EmpID/CurEmp parameter to achieve what I was attempting.